# unknown database format in access database

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a MS Access database, I have edited it in both Access 2007 and Access 2010, worked great for months and have alot of data in the tables. The application that uses is still works, but I can't open the database manually any more. I get the error `"unknown database format`" and `"The Visual Basic for Applications project in the database is corrupt"`. When I click ok on that dialog Access trys to repair my DB and when that is done I get the error "`id is not an index in this table"`.

At the moment I have only tryed to open a copy of my databas, since I CAN'T have the original databas not working. But how long will the application work? Or is this just an problem when opening in access? And ofc, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the undocumented -decompile switch in a Command window.  MAKE A BACKUP FIRST!  Access' native Compact & Repair will not fix that problem most of the time.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819780

Alternatively, you can also create a new, empty DB and copy all the tables, queries, forms, etc... into it.

Comment: Ok, but if my database is corrupt, why does my application work? What is worst case here? Can my data in anyway get deleted? How to best copy, didn't get the decompile to work...

Comment: Get deleted?  No.  Become irretrievable?  Yes.  As for how or why it happened, there's a potential myriad of reasons.  If it's a shared database, that's bad.  If you only have one front end, that's bad.  If it's on a network drive and it only has one front end and no back end, that's bad.  Did you try my Option 2?  Create a blank database and try importing the objects into it from the old database.  If that doesn't work, you can try opening it via Jet and copying the objects that way, but that's a pain in the butt.

Comment: If I wait with this 2 days is that much worse? (Dont know when it was corruted...) Since the application using the DB is running now, and the weekend would be better since I cant stop this durring runtime. Or Can the data entetred now be wrong in the DB?

Comment: Once corruption begins, it can spread exponentially.  I'd at LEAST make a back-up now, in case it becomes completely corrupt.

Comment: Thanks alot! Its backed up every day, but NO info Can really be lost thats the problem, does it stay in say one table, or does it spread wildly?... Is there any way to know what is corrupted?

Comment: Is the backup REPLACED every day, or is it backed up to a different file?  If it's just overwritten, that's not going to help you, because each new backup can have more and more corruption.

Comment: Ok, its replaced.... Just one question more, what does the corruption really mean? Is i the connections with autogenerated id that dosn't work or what is the error when this occure, I have all my connections between tables with my own uniqe key, not using the ID of the row for much, so if all rows would get a new id is no huge problem for me... But im not that lucky that this is the only error that Can happen?...

Comment: I took a copy and tryed to copy every table to a new database and it worked! So I will do the same to the live version this weekend and if its so much corrupted then, yea then atleast I have a day old db instead of none! Tanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the data in your database is currupted. Backup the db and try running Compact and repair:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/compact-and-repair-an-access-file-HP005187449.aspx

Comment: @Nick3, I did alittle googling and found this http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html where it's explained how to repair databases depending on the situation and http://help.wugnet.com/office2/Id-index-table-ftopict843584.html where someone managed to recover his database by exporting it to excel and importing it to a new ms access database